# What is the difference between Relative XPath and Minimal XPath?

Tags: xpath, firebug

Is there any difference between relative XPaths and minimal XPaths or both are same?

In Firebug there are two types of XPath mentioned in the options: 'XPath' and 'Minimal XPath'.

[image: *Copy XPath* and *Copy Minimal XPath* options within Firebug's *HTML* panel]

Comment: Relative and Minimal XPath are the same. There is difference between Absolute and Relative XPath.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two options is [described within the documentation to the *HTML* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel#Context_Menu).

The option *Copy Minimal XPath* is meant to make the XPath, which relates to one element, as short as possible. So the word 'minimal' actually refers to the length of the resulting XPath.
It is currently (Firebug 2.x) only available for elements, which have an ID. And for those elements it copies the XPath in the form of

```
//*[@id="elementID"]
```

where `elementID` represents the ID given within the `id` attribute of the element. So the words 'minimal' and 'relative' actually mean the same at the moment. Though future versions of Firebug may extend the feature to produce minimal XPaths for elements without ID. And those minimal paths don't necessarily have to be relative.

The option *Copy XPath* is available for all elements and copies an absolute XPath to an element, which e.g. looks like this:

```
/html/body/div/div[1]/div/div/table[4]/tbody/tr[17]/td[2]/a
```

Comment: As I have understood: Relative XPath is  //*[@id="elementID"] and Absolute XPath is:
/html/body/div/div[1]/div/div/table[4]/tbody/tr[17]/td[2]/a . My question is What is Minimal XPath?

Comment: Minimal XPath = relative XPath

Comment: So, Relative XPath and Minimal XPath is same. There is a difference between Absolute XPath and Relative (Minimal) XPath

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify that both words mean the same here. The word 'minimal' was just [preferred by the developers](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firebug/WeeklyUpdates/2014-01-28#Issues_from_last_time). And yes, the difference is between absolute and relative XPaths.

Comment: Also, _Copy XPath_ relies solely on _positional predicates_ in path expressions.

Comment: I described the naming and the reasoning behind it further, so it should be clear now. Note that if it's clear enough, you should give an upvote or accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian Zartner for your nice answer.